# How to get the full file path

Tags: php, javascript

When Im using a file field and browsing an image by its full path 
say `F:\Images\me.gif`.

how can i fetch this full path while submitting the form containing it by using php or javascript?

Thanxx in advance..

Comment: You cannot for security reasons http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=full+file+path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot for security reasons

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=full+file+path

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the file path from the client. I guess for security reasons.